# CSS Hover-эффект

Tags: css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Всем привет, есть проблема, связанная с hover-эффектом, а именно после того как срабатывает hover-эффект, стрелка(на картинке), появляется сразу, а не плавно, можете, пожалуйста, помочь разобраться с этим.

```css
.projects_container {
  margin-top: 70px;
}

.projects_description {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.projects_title {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-bottom: 25px;
  color: #555555;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
}

.projects_text {
  color: #8c8c8c;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 28px;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  width: 60%;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.projects_button {
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #ebebeb;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  height: 32px;
  width: 120px;
  color: #8c8c8c;
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 21px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.projects_button:focus {
  background-color: #998675;
  color: #f2f0ed;
}

.projects_portfolio {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 340px);
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 370px);
  align-items: center;
  grid-gap: 30px;
  margin-top: 40px;
  justify-content: center;
}

.project_title {
  margin: 0 auto;
  color: #c7b299;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-top: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.project_description {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 20px;
  color: #d1d1d1;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}

.project_button {
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 80px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.project_link {
  width: 170px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #998675;
  color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 3px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 23px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.project_link:hover {
  background-color: #111111;
  transition: .2s;
}

.project:hover {
  background-color: #362f2d;
  transition: background-color .5s;
}

.project .image {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.project .image .actions {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transform: translateY(100%);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: rgba(56, 46, 45, 0.7);
  transition: visibility .5s, transform .5s;
}

.project .image .actions a {
  font-size: 30px;
  margin: 0 10px;
  padding: 5px;
  color: #bcb3a2;
  transition: color .2s;
}

.project .image .actions a:hover {
  color: #fff;
}

.project .project_description {
  padding: 26px 15px;
  color: #a79a8a;
  border-radius: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

.project .project_description p {
  padding: 0;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.project .project_description .project_text {
  font-weight: 300;
  transition: color .5s;
}

.project:hover .image .actions {
  visibility: visible;
  transform: translateY(0);
  transition: visibility 0s, transform .5s;
}

.project:hover .project_description .project_text {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
}

.project_description:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 20px;
  bottom: 106px;
  border: 10px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 10px solid #fbfaf8;
}

.project:hover .project_description:after {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<section class="projects">
  <div class="projects_container">
    <div class="projects_description">
      <p class="projects_title">Our Latest Projects.</p>
      <div class="projects_text">Investigationes demonstraverunt lectores legere me lius quod ii legunt saepius. Claritas est etiam processus dynamicus, qui sequitur mutationem consuetudium.
      </div>
      <div class="projects_categories">
        <button class="projects_button" autofocus="">All</button>
        <button class="projects_button">Web Design</button>
        <button class="projects_button">Mobile App</button>
        <button class="projects_button">Illustration</button>
        <button class="projects_button">Photography</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="projects_portfolio">
      <div class="project">
        <div class="image">
          <img src="img/photo1.png" class="project_image">
          <div class="actions">
            <a href="#!">
              <i class="fa fa-link"></i>
            </a>
            <a href="#!">
              <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="project_description">
          <p class="project_title">Claritas Etiam Processus</p>
          <div class="project_text">Photography, Nature</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="project">
        <div class="image">
          <img src="img/photo.png" class="project_image">
          <div class="actions">
            <a href="#!">
              <i class="fa fa-link"></i>
            </a>
            <a href="#!">
              <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="project_description">
          <p class="project_title">Quam Nutamus Farum</p>
          <div class="project_text">Graphic Design, Mock-Up</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="project">
        <div class="image">
          <img src="img/photo2.png" class="project_image">
          <div class="actions">
            <a href="#!">
              <i class="fa fa-link"></i>
            </a>
            <a href="#!">
              <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="project_description">
          <p class="project_title">Usus Legentis Videntur</p>
          <div class="project_text">Photography, Holiday</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="project">
        <div class="image">
          <img src="img/photo3.png" class="project_image">
          <div class="actions">
            <a href="#!">
              <i class="fa fa-link"></i>
            </a>
            <a href="#!">
              <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="project_description">
          <p class="project_title">Claritas Etiam Processus</p>
          <div class="project_text">Photography, Nature</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="project">
        <div class="image">
          <img src="img/photo4.png" class="project_image">
          <div class="actions">
            <a href="#!">
              <i class="fa fa-link"></i>
            </a>
            <a href="#!">
              <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="project_description">
          <p class="project_title">Quam Nutamus Farum</p>
          <div class="project_text">Graphic Design, Mock-Up</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="project">
        <div class="image">
          <img src="img/photo5.png" class="project_image">
          <div class="actions">
            <a href="#!">
              <i class="fa fa-link"></i>
            </a>
            <a href="#!">
              <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="project_description">
          <p class="project_title">Usus Legentis Videntur</p>
          <div class="project_text">Photography, Holiday</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="project_button">
      <a href="#" class="project_link">load more</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Чему вы научитесь, если ДЗ будут за вас другие решать?

Comment: https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/KKdVpjW - примерно так

Comment: Поэтому я и задаю вопросы, чтобы научиться, по-моему это логично. Или вы хотите сказать, что в незнакомой для вас теме вы не будете задавать вопросы, чтобы разобраться?